# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.json.JSONObject.put(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object

Tags: eclipse, json, jboss, put

After some time to work with eclipse, jboss and json I get this library json-lib-0.9.jar  and added to jboss library so here the problem is that when I run the program I get

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   net.sf.json.JSONObject.put(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object

This error ocurs when i try to  make json.put(key,value). json is define as JSONObject.

Can someone help me please i don't know how resolve this one:(

Thanks,
    Radu

The exact error is

> [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/ExtJSFirstTry].[servlet.User]]
>   (http--127.0.0.1-8080-2) Servlet.service() for servlet servlet.User
>   threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   net.sf.json.JSONObject.put(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the JSON library to your build path. Follow this tutorial .. http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)

Comment: i think is a problem with Jboss not a build path i have in there libraries for  JSON. At build project i have no errors.